# Algorithm: find connections between towns with a limit of train changes

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

What algorithm would you use to create an application that given appropriate data (list of cities, train routes, train stations) is capable of returning a list of connection between any two user-selected cities?  The application has to choose only those connections that fall into the limit of accepted train-changes.

**Example:** I ask the application which train to take if I need to travel from Paris to Moscow with max. 1 stop/switch - the application returns a route: Train 1 (Paris-Berlin) -> Train 2 (Berlin->Moscow) (No direct connection exists).

**Graphical example** [image: Map]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSP9y.png

If I ask the system about possible connections from **Town A** to **Town G** I get a response:

- Brown Line (0 switches = direct)
- Brown Line to Town B / Orange Line to Town G (1 switch)
- Brown Line to Town B / Orange Line to Town D / Red Line to G (2 switch)
- ... all other possibilities

And thouh the 2nd and 3rd options are shorter than the 1st, it's the 1st that should have priority (since no train-switching is involved).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the only thing important is "number of stops/switches", then the problem is actually finding a shortest path in an unweighted  [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

The graph model is `G = (V,E)` where `V = {all possible stations}` and `E = { (u,v) | there is a train/route from station u to station v }`

**Note**: let's say you have a train which starts at a_0, and paths through a_1, a_2,...a_n: then E will contain: `(a_0,a_1),(a_0,a_2),..,(a_0,a_n)` and also `(a_1,a_2),(a_1,a_3),...` formally: for each `i < j` : (a_i,a_j) ∈ E.

[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) solves this problem, and is both [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Completeness) [always finds a solution if there is one] and [optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Optimality) [finds the shortest path].

If the edges [routes] are weighted, something like [dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) will be needed instead.

If you want a list of *all possible routes*, [Iterative-Deepening DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) could be used, without maintaining a visited set, and print all the paths found to the target up to the relevant depth. [BFS fails to return all paths with the counter example of a clique]

Comment: *@Queequeg The answer still holds. Given a source city s and target city t, run BFS from s. The path found by BFS is the shortest, and thus requires less switches then any other path.* <br/>But BFS would count every city/node as a switch and thats not true - i.e. brown line would not be chosen by BFS but its THE optimal solution

Comment: @Queequeg: I understand where your confusion was. I updated the answer [see the bolded Note], brown line will be chosen, since you will add a direct edge from `townA` to `townG`, so the shortest path found by BFS is `(townA,townG)` - which is the path without switches, as expected.

Comment: I get it. Nice idea! But the memory-overhead would be **huge** wouldnt it?

Comment: @Queequeg: Traditionally for graphs, `|E|=O(|V|^2)`, the number of edges is at most quadric to the number of vertices. This case is not different- since at the "worst case" you have a train that paths through all stations from each source, so `E = V x V` [you have a clique!], and you get `|E|=O(|V|^2)`. For this specific case, you get `|E| = O(|V|*longest_train_path)`, which is not worse then `O(|V|^2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to compute all pairs shortest paths. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm.